# Oblate spheroid equation help

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-coordinates, spheres

In the section

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#Reduced_(or_parametric)_latitude

Could someone tell me what $e$ and $f$ are in this first formula?

$$
\beta(\phi) = 
\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-e^2}\tan\phi\right)
=\tan^{-1}\left((1-f)\tan\phi\right)
$$

Also, is $\tan^{-1}$ the same as $\arctan$?

(Sorry, I am more used to typing formulas into programming source code, not using pen and paper.)

Thanks.

Comment: Scroll upward on that same entry to find [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#The_geometry_of_the_ellipsoid) which defines $f$ and $e^2$. $e$ is eccentricity.  $\tan^{-1} = \arctan$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e$ is the [eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)) of the polar cross-section.  $f$ is its oblateness, or (first) [flattening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flattening).  And yes, $\tan^{-1}$ is the same as arctan.